# Polymer Loading Slow in FireFox

Tags: firefox, polymer

This is a very vague question, but I have noticed that Polymer (both version 1.0 and 2.0) are very slow to load in Mozilla FireFox when you have a large number of custom elements.

Does anyone know any high-level, general strategies for increasing the load time?

The page loads near instantly in Chrome, but can take up to 4 seconds in FireFox. I can see on the network tab that the resources are coming just as fast, but the in-browser render time is significantly slower.

Or even a method to test exactly what is taking a while to load in FireFox - that would be very helpful. Right now, I can see each network request, but not just browser processing.

Thanks in advance!

**edit: the elements are all minified and vulcanized into 1 file.

Comment: There is one difference between Chrome and Firefox. Chrome has native web component support and Firefox hasn't. So to run web components in FF typically pollyfils are used first and it takes some time to load... And basically You can't do anything about it now, just wait  for a better times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the webcomponents-lite.min.js instead of webcomponents.js this should give you way better Performance in FF

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PRPL-pattern.

It's described here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/prpl-pattern/

Or use the optimizations `polymer build` gives you:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli